# is there a way for rviz to subscribe to topic of message typ sensor_msgs::ImagePtr?

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For image, I know that the Image Topic must be of type sensor_msgs::Image, but is there any feature in Rviz that would subscribe to any topic whose message type is sensor_msgs::ImagePtr?

---

Edit: @gvdhoorn I have ELP Camera usb-connected to Jetson TX1, and there is the package that publishes the video feed. And I want my laptop, which is connected to the Jetson via Ethernet crossover cable, to subscribe the video feed data (whether it is `sensor_msgs::Image` or `sensor_msgs::ImagePtr`) through Rviz. My old code published the data of type `sensor_msgs::Image` but for some reason, Rviz stopped when I added the topic for video feed, and I had to restart it. Any techniques as to how I should handle this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286608/is-there-a-way-for-rviz-to-subscribe-to-topic-of-message-typ-sensor_msgs::imageptr?/) by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:
Afaik `ImagePtr` is not a message type in `sensor_msgs`. It is only a type in the C++ code that gets generated by `gencpp` and then used in nodes that subscribe to `sensor_msgs/Image`. What are you trying to do exactly?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:
Publishing video/frames of a video could probably be done using `sensor_msgs/Image` directly but should preferably be done using [image_transport](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport). In all cases you wouldn't be publishing a `ImagePtr`, but an `Image` msg.

**Comment by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on 2018-03-27**:
I see. Thanks for your help. So my next question is whether there has ever been a project that remotely transmits video feed from a device A to  a device B using ROS.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:
Sure. All the time. It's not going to be the most efficient way to do it with `sensor_msgs/Image`, but it can be done.

Why do you ask?

**Comment by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on 2018-03-27**:
I tried to find any example projects like that, and I couldn't. I tried to do this myself using all available sources, and I'm still stuck.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:
Wouldn't just about every camera driver do that?

What about the [image_transport/Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials)?

**Comment by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on 2018-03-27**:
I thought so. But I guess, unlike mine, most camera-related projects I have examined are based on a single machine, so no one has ever experimented it in an environment with multiple connected machines. I should try with `sensor_msgs::Compressed`, which no one has ever tried with.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-27**:
I'm rather confused: ROS is supposed to make multi-machine networks transparent and using a compressed transport with `image_transport` is also transparent to the node (ie configured outside the node).

Can you describe what makes your 'multi machine' setup different / difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution. The `image_transport` package was not fully installed; the plugins for type `compressed` and `theora` were not installed. So I built the remaining types from source, and it is working fine. I don't know why other plugins were not installed when they were supposed to be (e.g. when I typed the command `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-image-transport`)

---

Originally posted by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) with karma: 62 on 2018-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-30**:\

> I don't know why other plugins were not installed when they were supposed to be

As far as I can tell, [image_transport_plugins](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport_plugins) is not a dependency of `image_transport`. So it would seem to be ok for them to not be installed.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-30**:\

> So I built the remaining types from source

unless you are planning to work on the transport plugins, I would strongly recommend to *not* build those from source. Just install `ros-kinetic-image-transport-plugins` and things should work.

**Comment by [chanhyeoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/29607/chanhyeoni/) on 2018-03-30**:
Thanks for your help. I removed the source from my catkin project and instead installed using commands. By the way, `ros-kinetic-image-transport-plugins` does not install the plugins. Rather, I used the command `sudo apt-get install ros-<distro>-<type>-image-transport`, and it is working fine.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-30**:
That is rather strange, as `ros-kinetic-image-transport-plugins` is supposed to bring in all plugins. Its dependencies are exactly the plugins.

But if things work for you, then ok.